# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'Class object'

Tags: c#, .net, exception, casting

I have a DataGrid.When i selected multiple rows and right click on it,then i changed the selected rows of one column True to False.

I wrote code as:

```
foreach (RiskSettings row in grdRiskAlerts.SelectedItems)
{
    viewTrue.Update(Query.EQ("-id",ObjectId.Parse(row.ID)), Update.Set("View", "False"));

}
```

I am using MongoDB as backend.

When i did same as above am getting error as

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'PravegaVegaFIXConsole.Configuration.RiskSettings'.

RiskSettings is my class. How to do type casting?

Comment: Please add more information: how is the RiskSettings related to DataRowView? what is the line of the error? Where's the RiskSettings code?

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if RiskSetting inherits from DataRowView. Otherwise you would have to use a creator method to create a RiskSettings from a DataRowView:

```
foreach (DataRowView drv in grdRiskAlerts.SelectedItems)
    {
        RiskSettings row=new RiskSettings(rdv);
        viewTrue.Update(Query.EQ("-id",ObjectId.Parse(row.ID)), Update.Set("View", "False"));

    }
```

And ensure that RiskSettings has a constructor that takes a DataRowView parameter. A better route may be to utilise the DataRowView entry, and extract the required data from that.

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestion.I did same as you told.Its working

Comment: After adding this i got another problem.In grid i have a link button. when i click on linkbutton that row in datagrid will display in new window.I added code as    RiskSettings rs = grdRiskAlerts.SelectedItem as RiskSettings;
           if (rs != null)
            {
                UpdateRiskAlerts updateRsk = new UpdateRiskAlerts();
                updateRsk.risklogs =rs;
                updateRsk.Show();
            } UpdateRiskAlerts is new window.risklogs is a property.I got same as above

Comment: I can't see the code properly. Can you update the question instead, or raise a new one?